# Data set structure and NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, na, data-cleaning

I've successfully rearranged the dataset into the format I want (see code annotation). However:

(a) I feel that there's a cleaner more efficient way to construct the database, maybe in the Tidyverse? My solution reads as a bit hacked together, and it takes a lot of code to implement. I'd really like to find an elegant and efficient way to do this, but need help.

(b) I am having trouble with the NA values. No matter what I do, R reads them as characters. I don't know if this is crucial for analysis as when I pass the as.numeric() function, it coerces these to NA values anyways. However, I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong, and how to 'do it right' going forward.

I've provided the code I'm using below, annotated, and dput() 5 lines from my (very large) data set are at the end of the code block to help re-create. Any help/feedback would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Load data set. This is how I'm loading the data. While the dput() output is at the 
# bottom of the code block, I've included this so people can see my steps for input, and
# how I'm inputting NA's.

pheno_sep_imp <- read.table(file="~/pheno_sep_imp.txt",
                            row.names = 1, header = TRUE,
                            na.strings = c(NA, "NA", " NA"), sep ="\t")
pheno_sep_imp <- data.frame(pheno_sep_imp,stringsAsFactors = T)
pheno_sep_imp <- mutate_if(pheno_sep_imp, is.integer, as.factor)
pheno_sep_imp <- mutate_if(pheno_sep_imp, is.character, as.factor)

# Remove anterior teeth
pheno_sep_imp <- pheno_sep_imp[c(1:6,22:46,62:86)]

# Re-code R3En to 3 for analysis
pheno_sep_imp[pheno_sep_imp == "R3En"] <- 3

# Re-code CON to NA for analysis. This is the point where NA's become a problem as they're # converting to 'character'.
pheno_sep_imp[pheno_sep_imp == "CON"] <- NA 

# Create an empty data frame for transformed data set
dta <- data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, 8, 
                        dimnames = list(c(), 
                                        c("Ind", "Geo",
                                          "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5",
                                          "Tooth"))), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

# Select names of columns from original data set for teeth/elements
nms <- names(pheno_sep_imp)
str_nms <- strsplit(nms, "_")
tooth_names <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(str_nms)){
  if(i>1){
    tooth_names <- c(tooth_names, paste0(str_nms[[i]][1]))
  }
}

# variable locations in pheno_sep_imp, put into dta
root_num <- seq(7, 52, by=5)  
count = 0
for(i in 1:dim(pheno_sep_imp)[1]){
  tmp <- pheno_sep_imp[i,]
  ind <- paste0("ind_",i)
  for(k in root_num){
    count <- count + 1 
    dta[count,] <- c(ind,toString(tmp[2][1,1]),
                     toString(tmp[k][[1]]), 
                     toString(tmp[k+1][[1]]),
                     toString((tmp[k+2][[1]])),
                     toString((tmp[k+3][[1]])),
                     toString((tmp[k+4][[1]])),
                     tooth_names[k-1])
  }
}

# check structure of data set
str(dta)

# check to see if NA's are NA's or 'characters'
class(dta$E1[1])

dta$E1 <- as.numeric(dta$E1) # Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion 
dta$E2 <- as.numeric(dta$E2) # Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion 
dta$E3 <- as.factor(dta$E3) # works as it should
dta$E4 <- as.factor(dta$E4) # works as it should
dta$E5 <- as.factor(dta$E5) # works as it should
dta$Geo <- as.factor(dta$Geo) # works as it should
dta$Ind <- as.factor(dta$Ind) # works as it should
dta <- dta[complete.cases(dta),]

View(dta) # Data is in the format I want/need for my analysis.

# dput() of 5 lines from my data set:

structure(list(Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), G1_Major_Human_Subdivisions = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Sahul_Pacific", "Sino_Americas", 
"Sub_Saharan_Africa", "Sunda_Pacific", "West_Eurasia"), class = "factor"), 
    G2_Continental_Group = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("Central_America", "Europe", "North_Africa", 
    "North_America", "Oceania", "South_America", "South_Asia", 
    "South_East_Asia", "Sub_Saharan_Africa"), class = "factor"), 
    G3_Continental_Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("American_Arctic", "Andaman_Archipelago", "Andean", 
    "Australia", "Carribbean", "Central_Africa", "Central_America", 
    "Central_Europe", "Eastern_Africa", "Eastern_Europe", "Indian_Sub_Continent", 
    "Indochinese_Peninsula", "Malay_Archipelago", "Melanesia", 
    "NA_Northeast_Woodlands", "NA_Northwest_Coast", "NA_Plains", 
    "NA_South_West", "NA_Subarctic", "NA_Unknown", "North_East_Africa", 
    "North_Western_Africa", "Northern_Africa", "Northern_Europe", 
    "Polynesia", "SA_Unknown", "Southern_Africa", "Southern_Europe", 
    "SSA_Unknown", "Western_Africa", "Western_Europe"), class = "factor"), 
    G4_Country_State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Alaska", 
    "American_Arctic_Unknown", "Andaman_Island", "Angola", "Argentina", 
    "Australia_Unknown", "Austrian", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", 
    "Canada", "Canary_Islands", "Central_Australia", "Chile", 
    "Congo", "Czechoslovakia", "East_India", "Egypt", "England", 
    "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", 
    "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Hungary", "India", "India_Unknown", 
    "Indonesia", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Kenya", "Malta", "Mozambique", 
    "Myanmar", "NA_Unknown", "Namibia", "New_South_Wales", "New_Zealand", 
    "Nicobar_Island", "Nigeria", "North_India", "Northern_Territory", 
    "Pakistan", "Papua_New_Guinea", "Peru", "Philippines", "Queensland", 
    "Russia", "SA_Unknown", "Solomon_Islands", "Somalia", "South_Africa", 
    "South_Australia", "South_East_Australia", "South_India", 
    "Spain", "Sri_Lanka", "SSA_Unknown", "Sudan", "Sweden", "Switzerland", 
    "Tanzania", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United_States", "Victoria", 
    "West_India", "Western_Australia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), 
    G5_Locality_Tribe = structure(c(57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
    57L), .Label = c("Aborigine", "Aboringine", "Ainaho", "Ainaho_Burao", 
    "Akamba", "Ali_Kush", "Amaponda", "Amaxhosa_Great_Winterberg", 
    "Apache", "Arawak", "Ashanti", "Badari", "Baffin_Island", 
    "Baiono", "Ballam_Coffa", "Bambuti_Pygmy", "Bantu_Kaoisoudo", 
    "Basuto", "Bechuanaland", "Bengal", "Bengal_Bangladesh", 
    "Berida", "Bihari", "Bingemma", "Brazaville", "Brittany", 
    "Bukoba", "Cape_Spencer_Aborigine", "Colombo", "Coorg", "Crime_Sebastopol", 
    "Crocodile _Island_Yan_nhanu", "Croydon_Queensland", "Darood", 
    "Darood_Hawiya", "Deccan_Berars", "Derby_Coast_Aborigine", 
    "Didali", "Dravidian", "Eingenadu", "Fanti", "Gannawarri", 
    "Gondaiaio", "Graubunden_Saint_Moritz", "Guanche", "Hadad", 
    "Halle", "Hariya", "Haya", "Hexham", "Hindu", "Hindustan", 
    "Hindustan_Bihar", "Huron", "Inuit", "Inuit_Eleanoran_Bay", 
    "Ipiutak", "Iroquois", "Java", "Jebel_Moya", "Jilili", "Kaduna", 
    "Kagoro", "Kalahari", "Kerma", "Ketchipawan", "Khanty_Kondinski", 
    "Khoikhoi", "Kikuyu", "Knysna_Cave", "Korana", "Kwaiawata _Island_Muyuw", 
    "Lapland", "Lazio", "Loddon_River_Aborigine", "Luanda", "Mackay_Aborigine", 
    "Makah", "Makua", "Malaysian", "Manatee_Cradock", "Manitoba", 
    "Maori", "Mem_Mem", "Minorca", "Mortlake_Aborigine", "Mumbai_Parsi", 
    "Muri_Province", "Murray_River", "Murray_River_Aborigine", 
    "Murua_Island_Muyuw", "Muyuw_Kwaiawata_Island", "Nagada", 
    "Naharhmpikya_Sinhalese", "Native_American", "New_Britain", 
    "New_Westminster", "Newcastle", "North_Queensland ", "Oriomo_River_Daudai", 
    "Paestum", "Pagi_Island", "Pakistan", "Paliyan_Tribe", "Paris", 
    "Pasamayo", "Pathan", "Patna", "Perth", "Plympton_Aborigine", 
    "Port_Elizabeth", "Punjab", "Rio_Gallegos", "Rome", "Salekhard", 
    "Sardinia", "Sicily", "Sioux", "South_Wilshire", "St_Bernard", 
    "Swanport_Aborigine", "Tagalog_Island", "Tal_Horr", "Tegera_Well", 
    "Teita", "Teso", "Thessaly", "Tigara", "Toszeg", "Upper_Congo_River", 
    "Valparaiso", "Vancouver_Island", "Veddah", "Vienna", "Walvis_Bay", 
    "Wollongong", "Wynberg_San", "Yola", "Yoruba_Ilorin", "Zuni"
    ), class = "factor"), RI1_MAX_E1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), RI1_MAX_E2 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), RI1_MAX_E3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), RI1_MAX_E4 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("E", "G", "P", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    RI1_MAX_E5 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("O", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), RI2_MAX_E1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "CON"), class = "factor"), 
    RI2_MAX_E2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "CON"), class = "factor"), RI2_MAX_E3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1", "CON"), class = "factor"), 
    RI2_MAX_E4 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("CON", 
    "E", "G", "P", "W"), class = "factor"), RI2_MAX_E5 = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CON", "O", "R", "R4"), class = "factor"), 
    RC1_MAX_E1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    RC1_MAX_E2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), RC1_MAX_E3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1"), class = "factor"), 
    RC1_MAX_E4 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("E", 
    "EBi", "G", "P", "W"), class = "factor"), RC1_MAX_E5 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("O", "R", "R5"), class = "factor"), 
    RP3_MAX_E1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor"), RP3_MAX_E2 = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    RP3_MAX_E3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B1L1", "B1L2", "B2L1", "M1D1", "M1D1L1"), class = "factor"), 
    RP3_MAX_E4 = structure(c(1L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L), .Label = c("BGLG", 
    "BGLKBi", "BHLE", "BHLG", "BKLG", "BPLG", "BWLG", "E", "H", 
    "HBi", "K", "KBi", "MEDGLG", "MGDGLE", "MGDGLG", "MPDPLE", 
    "P", "PBi", "W"), class = "factor"), RP3_MAX_E5 = structure(c(3L, 
    11L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 10L), .Label = c("BR2LR", "BR4LR", "BRLR", 
    "BRLR2", "i2", "i5", "MRDRLR", "O", "R", "R2", "R4", "R5"
    ), class = "factor"), RP4_MAX_E1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    RP4_MAX_E2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), RP4_MAX_E3 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1", "B2L1", "B2L2", 
    "M1D1L1"), class = "factor"), RP4_MAX_E4 = structure(c(13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("BELG", "BGLG", "BHLG", 
    "BKLG", "E", "G", "H", "HBi", "K", "KBi", "MGDGLE", "MLFBiDG", 
    "P", "PBi", "W"), class = "factor"), RP4_MAX_E5 = structure(c(10L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("BR2L4", "BR2LR", "BRLR", 
    "i2", "i5", "MRDRLR", "O", "R", "R2", "R4", "R5"), class = "factor"), 
    RM1_MAX_E1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), RM1_MAX_E2 = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), 
    RM1_MAX_E3 = structure(c(9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("B1L1", 
    "M1D1", "M1D1L1", "M1D1L2", "M1D2", "M1D2L1", "M1L1", "M2D1", 
    "M2D1L1", "M2D1L2", "M2D2L1", "M2D2L2", "M3D1L1", "MB1DB1ML1DL1"
    ), class = "factor"), RM1_MAX_E4 = structure(c(51L, 32L, 
    32L, 45L, 32L, 38L), .Label = c("BKLG", "BPLG", "MBPDBEMLEDLG", 
    "MDFLE", "MDFLG", "MDFLK", "MDFLP", "MEDELE", "MEDELP", "MEDGLG", 
    "MEDKLE", "MEDPLE", "MEDWLK", "MHDELP", "MHDPLE", "MHDPLP", 
    "MKDELE", "MKDELP", "MKDGLE", "MKDGLG", "MKDGLP", "MKDPLE", 
    "MKDPLG", "MKDPLP", "MLFBiDG", "MLFBiDP", "MLFDE", "MPBiDPLG", 
    "MPBiDPLK", "MPBiDPLP", "MPDELE", "MPDELG", "MPDELK", "MPDELP", 
    "MPDGLE", "MPDGLG", "MPDGLP", "MPDLF", "MPDLFBi", "MPDP", 
    "MPDPLE", "MPDPLG", "MPDPLK", "MPDPLP", "MPDWLE", "MPDWLG", 
    "MPDWLP", "MWBiDPLP", "MWBiDWLG", "MWDE", "MWDELE", "MWDELG", 
    "MWDELK", "MWDELP", "MWDGLE", "MWDGLG", "MWDGLK", "MWDGLP", 
    "MWDGLR", "MWDGLW", "MWDKLE", "MWDKLG", "MWDKLP", "MWDLF", 
    "MWDLFBi", "MWDPDE", "MWDPLE", "MWDPLG", "MWDPLK", "MWDPLP", 
    "MWDPLW", "MWDWLE", "MWDWLG", "MWDWLK", "MWDWLP", "P"), class = "factor"), 
    RM1_MAX_E5 = structure(c(29L, 42L, 22L, 22L, 20L, 22L), .Label = c("BOLR", 
    "MBODBOMLRDLR", "Mi2DOLO", "Mi2DOLR", "Mi2DR4LR4", "Mi2DRLO", 
    "Mi2DRLR", "Mi2DRLR2", "Mi3DOLR", "Mi3DRLO", "Mi3DRLR", "Mi4DRLR", 
    "Mi5DOLO", "Mi5DOLR", "Mi5DRLO", "Mi5DRLR", "MODi2", "MODLi5", 
    "MODOLO", "MODOLR", "MODRLO", "MODRLR", "MODRLR2", "MR2DO", 
    "MR2DOLO", "MR2DOLR", "MR2DR2LO", "MR2DRLO", "MR2DRLR", "MR2DRLR2", 
    "MR4DOLO", "MR4DOLR", "MR4DRLO", "MR4DRLR", "MR5DOLO", "MR5DRLO", 
    "MR5DRLR", "MRDOLO", "MRDOLR", "MRDRLi5", "MRDRLO", "MRDRLR", 
    "R2"), class = "factor"), RM2_MAX_E1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    RM2_MAX_E2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), RM2_MAX_E3 = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1", "M1B1D1L1", 
    "M1D1", "M1D1L1", "M1D2L1", "M2D1L1", "MB1DB1ML1DL1", "ML3D1"
    ), class = "factor"), RM2_MAX_E4 = structure(c(45L, 13L, 
    13L, 51L, 57L, 70L), .Label = c("BGLG", "BHLG", "BKLG", "BKLK", 
    "BKLP", "BLF", "BPLG", "H", "HBi", "KBi", "MBEDBEMLEDLE", 
    "MBWDBGMLEDLE", "MDFDLF", "MDFLE", "MDFLG", "MDFMLF", "MDFMLFBi", 
    "MEDELE", "MEDELG", "MEDGLE", "MEDGLG", "MEDGLK", "MEDKLG", 
    "MEDWLG", "MGDGLG", "MHBiDELE", "MHDELE", "MHDELG", "MHDELP", 
    "MHDGLG", "MHDGLP", "MHDWLP", "MKDELE", "MKDELG", "MKDELP", 
    "MKDGLE", "MKDGLG", "MKDGLP", "MKDLF", "MKDPLE", "MKDPLP", 
    "MLFBGDLF", "MLFBiDE", "MLFBiDG", "MLFBiDLF", "MLFBiDP", 
    "MLFBiDW", "MLFBiMDF", "MLFDE", "MLFDG", "MLFDLF", "MLFDLFBi", 
    "MLFDP", "MLFDW", "MLFMDF", "MPDELE", "MPDELG", "MPDELK", 
    "MPDELP", "MPDGLE", "MPDGLG", "MPDGLP", "MPDKLG", "MPDLF", 
    "MPDPLE", "MPDPLG", "MPDPLP", "MPDWLG", "MWDELE", "MWDELG", 
    "MWDELK", "MWDELP", "MWDGLE", "MWDGLG", "MWDGLK", "MWDGLP", 
    "MWDKLE", "MWDKLG", "MWDLF", "MWDLFBi", "MWDPLE", "MWDPLG", 
    "MWDPLK", "MWDPLP", "MWDWLE", "MWDWLG", "MWDWLP", "P", "W"
    ), class = "factor"), RM2_MAX_E5 = structure(c(28L, 16L, 
    20L, 16L, 25L, 44L), .Label = c("BOLO", "BOLR", "BRLR", "i2", 
    "i3", "MBRDBRMLRDLR", "MDi2LO", "MDi2LR", "Mi2DOLR", "Mi2DRLO", 
    "Mi2DRLR", "Mi3DRLO", "Mi5DOLR", "Mi5DRLR", "MLi2DO", "MLi2DR", 
    "MLi3DR", "MLi4DO", "MLi5DO", "MLi5DR", "MLODLi2", "MODi5LR", 
    "MODLi2", "MODOLO", "MODOLR", "MODR4LR", "MODRLO", "MODRLR", 
    "MR2DOLO", "MR2DOLR", "MR2DRLO", "MR2DRLR", "MR4DOLO", "MR4DOLR", 
    "MR4DRLO", "MR4DRLR", "MR5DRLO", "MR5DRLR", "MRBRDRLR", "MRDLi2", 
    "MRDOLO", "MRDOLR", "MRDRLO", "MRDRLR", "O", "R", "R2"), class = "factor"), 
    RM3_MAX_E1 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "CON"), class = "factor"), RM3_MAX_E2 = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "CON"
    ), class = "factor"), RM3_MAX_E3 = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1", "B2D1L1", "CON", "M1B1D1L1", 
    "M1D1", "M1D1L1", "M1D1L2", "M1D2", "M1D2L1", "M2D1", "M2D1L1", 
    "M2D2", "MB1DB1ML1DL1", "ML3D1"), class = "factor"), RM3_MAX_E4 = structure(c(70L, 
    49L, 70L, 49L, 61L, 49L), .Label = c("BGLG", "BGLK", "BKDGLG", 
    "BKLG", "CON", "E", "G", "HBi", "K", "MBEDBGMLEDLG", "MBEDBGMLGDLG", 
    "MBGDBGMLGDLG", "MDF", "MDFDLF", "MDFLE", "MDFLG", "MEDELE", 
    "MEDELP", "MEDGLE", "MEDGLG", "MEDLF", "MEDP", "MEDWLE", 
    "MGDELG", "MGDGLG", "MGDLF", "MHBiDELG", "MHBiDH", "MHBiDHBi", 
    "MHDGLE", "MHDGLG", "MHDH", "MHDK", "Mi", "MKDELE", "MKDELG", 
    "MKDGLE", "MKDGLG", "MKDGLP", "MKDKLG", "MKDLF", "MKDP", 
    "MKDPLG", "MLFBiDE", "MLFBiDG", "MLFBiDLF", "MLFDE", "MLFDG", 
    "MLFDLF", "MLFDP", "MLFMDF", "MPBiDGLG", "MPBiDW", "MPDELE", 
    "MPDELG", "MPDGLE", "MPDGLG", "MPDGLP", "MPDGLPBi", "MPDH", 
    "MPDLF", "MPDP", "MPDPBi", "MPDPLG", "MWBEDELG", "MWDELE", 
    "MWDELG", "MWDELP", "MWDGLE", "MWDGLG", "MWDGLP", "MWDH", 
    "MWDKLG", "MWDLF", "MWDPLG", "MWDW", "MWDWLG", "P"), class = "factor"), 
    RM3_MAX_E5 = structure(c(45L, 45L, 45L, 17L, 29L, 45L), .Label = c("BOLR", 
    "BR2DRLR", "BRLO", "BRLR", "CON", "i2", "i3", "i5", "MBRBDRMLRDLR", 
    "MBRDBRMLRDLR", "MDi2LR", "Mi2DOLR", "Mi2DR", "Mi2DRLR", 
    "Mi3DRLR", "Mi5DRLR", "MLi2DR", "MLi4DR", "MODi5LR", "MODLi2", 
    "MODLi3", "MODLi5", "MODO", "MODOLO", "MODOLR", "MODR", "MODR4", 
    "MODRLO", "MODRLR", "MODRLR2", "MR2DOLO", "MR2DR2", "MR2DRLO", 
    "MR2DRLR", "MR4DR2", "MR4DR4", "MR4DRLO", "MR4DRLR", "MRBRDRLR", 
    "MRDLi5", "MRDOLR", "MRDR", "MRDR2", "MRDRLO", "MRDRLR", 
    "O", "R", "R2", "R4"), class = "factor"), ri1_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), ri1_mand_E2 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    ri1_mand_E3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B1L1"), class = "factor"), ri1_mand_E4 = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("E", "G", "K", "P", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    ri1_mand_E5 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("i2", 
    "O", "R", "R2", "R4"), class = "factor"), ri2_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "CON"), class = "factor"), 
    ri2_mand_E2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "CON"), class = "factor"), ri2_mand_E3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1", "CON"), class = "factor"), 
    ri2_mand_E4 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("CON", 
    "E", "H", "K", "P", "W"), class = "factor"), ri2_mand_E5 = structure(c(5L, 
    5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("CON", "i2", "i5", "O", "R", 
    "R2", "R4"), class = "factor"), rc1_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    rc1_mand_E2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), rc1_mand_E3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1"), class = "factor"), 
    rc1_mand_E4 = structure(c(2L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("BGLG", 
    "E", "G", "H", "K", "P", "W", "WBi"), class = "factor"), 
    rc1_mand_E5 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("BRLR", 
    "i2", "O", "R", "R2", "R4", "R5"), class = "factor"), rp3_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    rp3_mand_E2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor"), rp3_mand_E3 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1", "M1D1L1"), class = "factor"), 
    rp3_mand_E4 = structure(c(7L, 7L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("BGLG", 
    "BWLG", "E", "G", "H", "K", "P", "T", "TBi", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    rp3_mand_E5 = structure(c(7L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("BRLR", 
    "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "MRDRLR", "O", "R", "R2", "R4"), class = "factor"), 
    rp4_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    rp4_mand_E2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor"), rp4_mand_E3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B1L1"), class = "factor"), 
    rp4_mand_E4 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("E", 
    "G", "HBi", "K", "P", "T", "TBi", "W"), class = "factor"), 
    rp4_mand_E5 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("i5", 
    "O", "R", "R2", "R4"), class = "factor"), rm1_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "R3En"), class = "factor"), 
    rm1_mand_E2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2", 
    "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "factor"), rm1_mand_E3 = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("M1D1", "M1D1L1", "M2D1", 
    "M2D1L1", "M2D2", "M2D2L1", "M2D3", "M3D1", "M3D2", "M3D3"
    ), class = "factor"), rm1_mand_E4 = structure(c(17L, 36L, 
    36L, 45L, 40L, 40L), .Label = c("MHBiDELG", "MHBiDH", "MHBiDHBi", 
    "MHBiDK", "MHBiDKBi", "MHBiDP", "MHBiDPBi", "MHBiDPLE", "MHBiDPLG", 
    "MHBiDWLG", "MHDE", "MHDELG", "MHDG", "MHDGLG", "MHDH", "MHDK", 
    "MHDP", "MHDPBi", "MHDPLE", "MHDPLG", "MHDWLG", "MKBiDK", 
    "MKBiDP", "MKDH", "MKDK", "MKDP", "MPBiDELG", "MPBiDK", "MPBiDKLG", 
    "MPBiDP", "MPBiDPLE", "MPBiDPLG", "MPDE", "MPDELE", "MPDELG", 
    "MPDGLG", "MPDK", "MPDKBi", "MPDKLG", "MPDP", "MPDPBi", "MPDPLE", 
    "MPDPLG", "MPDPLP", "MPDPLW", "MPDWLG", "MPDWLW"), class = "factor"), 
    rm1_mand_E5 = structure(c(34L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 34L, 39L), .Label = c("Mi2Di2", 
    "Mi2Di3", "Mi2Di5", "Mi2DO", "Mi2DOLR", "Mi2DR", "Mi2DR2", 
    "Mi2DRLR", "Mi3Di2", "Mi3Di4", "Mi3DO", "Mi3DOLO", "Mi3DOLR", 
    "Mi3DRLR", "Mi4Di2", "Mi4Di4", "Mi4DO", "Mi4DR4", "Mi5Di2", 
    "Mi5Di5", "Mi5DO", "Mi5DOLR", "Mi5DR2", "Mi5DR4", "Mi5DRLR", 
    "MODO", "MODR", "MODRLR", "MR2Di2", "MR2Di2LR", "MR2Di3", 
    "MR2Di4", "MR2Di5", "MR2DO", "MR2DOLO", "MR2DOLR", "MR2DR", 
    "MR2DR2", "MR2DR4", "MR2DR5", "MR2DRLR", "MR4Di2", "MR4Di2LR", 
    "MR4Di3", "MR4Di4", "MR4DO", "MR4DOLR", "MR4DR", "MR4DR4", 
    "MR4DRLO", "MR4DRLR", "MR5DOLR", "MR5DR4", "MR5DRLO", "MRDO", 
    "MRDOLR", "MRDR"), class = "factor"), rm2_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "R3En"), class = "factor"), 
    rm2_mand_E2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), rm2_mand_E3 = structure(c(6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("A", "B1D1L1", "B2L1", "B2L2", 
    "M1B1D1", "M1D1", "M1D1L1", "M1D2", "M2D1", "M2D1L1", "M2D2", 
    "M3D1"), class = "factor"), rm2_mand_E4 = structure(c(5L, 
    39L, 30L, 5L, 21L, 39L), .Label = c("BGDPLG", "BHBiLP", "BPLK", 
    "BPLP", "Cs", "CsBi", "G", "MDF", "MEDE", "MGDPLW", "MHBiDE", 
    "MHBiDH", "MHBiDK", "MHBiDP", "MHBiDPBi", "MHDE", "MHDELP", 
    "MHDG", "MHDH", "MHDHBi", "MHDK", "MHDP", "MHDPLG", "MKBiDK", 
    "MKBiDP", "MKDE", "MKDG", "MKDH", "MKDHBi", "MKDK", "MKDP", 
    "MKDPBi", "MPBiDGLG", "MPBiDP", "MPDE", "MPDG", "MPDH", "MPDK", 
    "MPDP", "MPDPLG"), class = "factor"), rm2_mand_E5 = structure(c(5L, 
    17L, 18L, 7L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("Bi5Li2", "BR2LO", "BRDOLR", 
    "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5", "Mi2Di2", "Mi2DO", "Mi2DR", "Mi2DR2", 
    "Mi3DO", "Mi3DR", "Mi4DO", "Mi5DO", "Mi5DR", "MODO", "MODR", 
    "MR2Di2", "MR2Di3", "MR2DO", "MR2DOLR", "MR2DR", "MR2DR2", 
    "MR2DR4", "MR2DRLR", "MR4Di2", "MR4DO", "MR4DOLR", "MR4DR", 
    "MR4DR4", "MR4DRLR", "MR5DO", "MRDO", "MRDOLR", "MRDR", "R", 
    "R2"), class = "factor"), rm3_mand_E1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "CON", "R3En", "R3Pa"
    ), class = "factor"), rm3_mand_E2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "CON"), class = "factor"), 
    rm3_mand_E3 = structure(c(6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B2L1", "CON", "M1B1D1", "M1B2D1", "M1D1", "M1D1L1", "M2B1D1", 
    "M2D1", "M2D1L1", "M2D2", "M3D1"), class = "factor"), rm3_mand_E4 = structure(c(3L, 
    25L, 25L, 44L, 32L, 47L), .Label = c("BHLP", "CON", "Cs", 
    "E", "G", "K", "MCsLG", "MDF", "MDFLG", "MEDELG", "MEDG", 
    "MELE", "MGBGDE", "MGBPDK", "MGDK", "MHBiDK", "MHBiDP", "MHDE", 
    "MHDELG", "MHDG", "MHDGLG", "MHDK", "MHDP", "MHDPLG", "Mi", 
    "MKBGDG", "MKBiDK", "MKBiDP", "MKDE", "MKDG", "MKDGLG", "MKDK", 
    "MKDP", "MKDPLG", "MKDW", "MPBGDE", "MPBGDG", "MPBGDP", "MPBiDE", 
    "MPBiDK", "MPBPDE", "MPDE", "MPDELG", "MPDG", "MPDGLG", "MPDK", 
    "MPDP", "MPDPLE", "MPDPLG", "MPDWLG", "MWDELG", "MWDP", "P"
    ), class = "factor"), rm3_mand_E5 = structure(c(3L, 42L, 
    42L, 23L, 33L, 26L), .Label = c("BR2LO", "CON", "i2", "i3", 
    "i5", "Mi2BRDR", "Mi2Di2", "Mi2DO", "Mi2DOLR", "Mi2DR", "Mi2DRLR", 
    "Mi3DO", "Mi3DOLR", "Mi3LR", "Mi4DR", "Mi5DO", "Mi5DR", "Mi5DRLR", 
    "MOBRDO", "MOBRDR", "MODO", "MODOLR", "MODR", "MODRLR", "MR2BRDR", 
    "MR2DO", "MR2DOLR", "MR2DR", "MR2DR2", "MR2DR4", "MR2DRLR", 
    "MR4Di5", "MR4DO", "MR4DR", "MR4DR4", "MR4DRLR", "MRBR2DO", 
    "MRBRDR", "MRDR", "MRDRLR", "O", "R", "R2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("99_1_192", 
"99_1_194", "99_1_196", "99_1_197", "99_1_198", "99_1_201"), class = "data.frame")
```